# How can I set a fixed height and width as percentage for div with position: relative?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of divs and each div contains sub divs each of which contain images. I have a problem wherein not all image are uniformly sized and hence the div containing the img tag expands depending on the image dimensions. I cant set the div height and width in terms of pixels, as it has work across mobile devices. Please let me know if there is a way to have fixed div size in terms of percentage irrespective of the image size.

CSS:

```
  .listItem {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 #000;
    margin: 1%;
    background: #ffffff;
  }

  .programContent {
    float: right;
    right: 2%;
    top: 0%;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #737373;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.38);
    width:  20%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
  }

  .programContent img{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 75%;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="listItem">
  <div class="programContent">
    <img src="imageURL">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="listItem">
  <div class="programContent">
    <img src="imageURL">
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fayazvf/owrk9cd2/2/

Answer (score 1):

For the DIV that contains the image, define both height and width. see example below:

```
.div-that-contains-image {
       width: 25%; /* Adjust as needed */
       height: 25%; /* Adjust as needed */
       overflow: hidden; /* cuts of whatever that goes beyond the given dimension */
    }
```

For the image itself, either the width or the height, must be set to auto
to it doesn't deteriorate. see the example below.

```
.div-that-contains-image img {
      width: 100%; /* Equals the .div-that-contains-image */
      height: auto; /* Allows the image the breathing space so it doesn't deteriorate */

 }
```

Comment: That's not true. % is perfect for mobile devices. For mobile always use % for the width and auto for height. That way, as your content shrinks and stretches, it won't over lap because the height is auto.

Comment: You have the CSS in the wrong place. CSS goes to the top right hand side. Check this link now http://jsfiddle.net/owrk9cd2/7/ it is perfect.